# Setting a value on load of a table

Tags: google-app-maker

Why doesn't this work? It is definitely allowed/encouraged by the autocomplete

I have this in the onDataLoad section for the row of the table (because I only want it to run if the item shows up in the specific search).

```
var item = widget.datasource.item;
console.log("table attached "+item.Name);
item.iscorrect= true;
console.log(item.iscorrect);
```

This outputs "table attached: name" and then a blank row.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo such as `Iscorrect` instead of `iscorrect`?

Comment: yes, iscorrect is actually pseudocode, but the variable I am using autocompletes the field name so I know it isn't a typo issue.

Comment: I just tested a similar scenario and it works for me... there must be something else that you are missing out.

Comment: So is 'iscorrect' a field in your datasource? Is the datasource maybe in manual save mode?

Comment: I will check the save modes, that sounds like a smart instinct